# Make predictions on new data using a SVM in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, svm

I trained a SVM classifcation model using "fitcsvm" function and tested with the test data set. Now I want to use this model to predict the classes of new (previously unseen) data. What should be done ?

Following is the code I used.

```
load FeatureLabelsNum.csv
load FeatureOne.csv

X = FeatureOne(1:42,:);
y = FeatureLabelsNum(1:42,:);

%dividing the dataset into training and testing 
rand_num = randperm(42);

%training Set
X_train = X(rand_num(1:34),:);
y_train = y(rand_num(1:34),:);

%testing Set
X_test = X(rand_num(34:end),:);
y_test = y(rand_num(34:end),:);

%preparing validation set out of training set

c = cvpartition(y_train,'k',5);

SVMModel = 
fitcsvm(X_train,y_train,'Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','RBF',...
'KernelScale','auto','OutlierFraction',0.05);

CVSVMModel = crossval(SVMModel);

classLoss = kfoldLoss(CVSVMModel)
classOrder = SVMModel.ClassNames
sv = SVMModel.SupportVectors;

figure
gscatter(X_train(:,1),X_train(:,2),y_train)
hold on
plot(sv(:,1),sv(:,2),'ko','MarkerSize',10)
legend('Resampled','Non','Support Vector')
hold off


X_test_w_best_feature =X_test(:,:);
bp = (predict(SVMModel,X_test)== y_test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use the predict function in your script, however, just pass the new data in and score will contain your predicted labels.

```
[~,score] = predict(SVMModel,X_new_data);
```